# BeautifulSoup findAll return empty list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

So i wanted to get all "b" tags with "price" class form this [website](https://warframe.market/items/nami_skyla_prime_blueprint), but soup.findAll return empty list with 0 elements. But when I try the same thing, but with local html file, everything just works fine.

I've searched all over the internet, but nothing seems to help.

The code itself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://warframe.market/items/nami_skyla_prime_blueprint'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('b')
print(tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it). To load the data into pandas dataframe you can use this example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = (
    "https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/nami_skyla_prime_blueprint/orders"
)

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(api_url).json()["payload"]["orders"])
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("user").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| platform | region | order_type | creation_date | platinum | quantity | last_update | visible | id | reputation | region | avatar | last_seen | ingame_name | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pc | en | sell | 2018-03-24T13:19:44.000+00:00 | 5 | 1 | 2018-03-24T13:19:44.000+00:00 | True | 5ab6507049ef000fcf1920a9 | 0 | en |  | 2022-07-30T18:00:20.943+00:00 | lastcrist | 62e56f91330ca40377b19895 | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2019-01-10T18:21:06.000+00:00 | 14 | 1 | 2022-07-26T18:45:05.000+00:00 | True | 5c378d12af045700a4291477 | 3 | en |  | 2022-07-27T11:04:01.133+00:00 | kekxqt | 5a0628ddc611360011c7a66e | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2019-12-09T07:11:43.000+00:00 | 35 | 1 | 2021-12-02T04:32:53.000+00:00 | True | 5dedf3afc72155005cf4028c | 968 | en | user/avatar/55f4e189b66f831701dbff77.png?0fe7b910face5429601e7085d289f869 | 2022-07-30T16:18:02.366+00:00 | Sahysa | 55f4e189b66f831701dbff77 | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2020-02-04T03:29:02.000+00:00 | 13 | 1 | 2022-07-29T23:22:45.000+00:00 | True | 5e38e4fe7b0275005e6d29a9 | 4 | en |  | 2022-07-30T06:40:38.150+00:00 | YellowSnowBoi | 5b3c268c0c3535012e9b6ee3 | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2020-03-29T20:14:39.000+00:00 | 15 | 1 | 2022-07-24T18:14:30.000+00:00 | True | 5e8101aff3441505a6b292c6 | 19 | en | user/avatar/5b2931d4eb069f04986adb6d.png?822ece14d8951796338ef3739d5c6b2c | 2022-07-29T20:55:01.617+00:00 | xblq | 5b2931d4eb069f04986adb6d | offline |
| pc | ko | sell | 2020-11-07T09:15:58.000+00:00 | 9 | 1 | 2020-11-07T09:15:58.000+00:00 | True | 5fa665ced5b8ca0262d04cf0 | 0 | ko |  | 2022-07-30T17:33:05.154+00:00 | blazespirit | 5a4380778c474d007384823b | ingame |
| pc | en | sell | 2021-02-07T12:42:27.000+00:00 | 15 | 1 | 2021-12-26T14:35:01.000+00:00 | True | 601fe033ec5e7e01d47859a1 | 3 | en | user/avatar/600fcf3dc59d3703156a15e3.png?5f9404dcf7c36b3200d2eaab5ed9dba9 | 2022-07-30T10:26:53.816+00:00 | pavelfizek | 600fcf3dc59d3703156a15e3 | offline |
| pc | en | buy | 2021-02-12T14:34:49.000+00:00 | 10 | 6 | 2022-07-20T21:11:53.000+00:00 | True | 60269209039a2702632da531 | 412 | en | user/avatar/598d8bf2d3ffb648a838abba.png?dfe50b7091f0e8c44b63976a700eebd9 | 2022-07-30T10:02:13.214+00:00 | Xnidior | 598d8bf2d3ffb648a838abba | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2021-02-13T03:24:21.000+00:00 | 10 | 1 | 2022-07-23T06:48:55.000+00:00 | True | 602746651c9894026f386fb0 | 2 | en |  | 2022-07-28T02:31:25.058+00:00 | Reaper575 | 5cd904444532a609fef941db | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2021-03-13T18:03:01.000+00:00 | 15 | 1 | 2022-07-22T14:35:07.000+00:00 | True | 604cfe55171b1903005aa375 | 23 | en | user/avatar/5c1cc13e6ad4a90015110a59.png?3eca6f848f62560068b7c0f17f141d6d | 2022-07-27T11:36:30.529+00:00 | -CG-Luthix | 5c1cc13e6ad4a90015110a59 | offline |
| pc | ru | buy | 2021-04-03T05:56:22.000+00:00 | 5 | 1 | 2022-04-07T10:38:12.000+00:00 | True | 606803861a02f00165d2965c | 2 | ru | user/avatar/624ebb41596f2f00881ce522.png?c1556e2a317fe8dfbd7e86ba051e371a | 2022-07-27T14:19:19.788+00:00 | 1FioLet1 | 624ebb41596f2f00881ce522 | offline |
| pc | en | sell | 2021-06-11T13:42:09.000+00:00 | 20 | 1 | 2021-06-11T13:42:09.000+00:00 | True | 60c368311970de00c952915f | 0 | en |  | 2022-07-30T02:14:54.187+00:00 | NEXUREX21 | 6039915229f04b0128def8fa | offline |

...

Comment: Andrej, how do you paste that table format? I'm stuck with pasting dataframes and then formatting as code, doesn;t look so good. What's the secret?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire When you do `print(df.to_markdown())` it will print the table in markdown format. Just copy it and paste here, SO will format it correctly.

Comment: @AndrejKesely here goes the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181286/beautifulsoup-findall-return-empty-list. OP does not understand that this data cannot be scraped using request-response